# Interpreter for Brainfuck in Haskell

Tags: haskell, interpreter, brainfuck

I am doing a Haskell-related problem in [codewar](https://www.codewars.com/kata/my-smallest-code-interpreter-aka-brainf-star-star-k/train/haskell), which is to write an interpreter for Brainfuck, the famous esoteric language.

Initially, I was thinking about writing the program using `Array`. Immediately after I started to implement the interpreter, I realized how inefficient the interpreter would be because there are many changes to the array. Then I switched to use `STArray`. But aside from holding an array of data pointers, I also need a mutable reference for the output `String`, which is impossible in `STArray`. So I was totally stunned.

Writing a monadic parser might be a good idea, I thought then. But it turns out I don't know what kind of expressions I should use to model the problem. I only read a few papers on monadic parsing style and that's all. Brainfuck is much more complicated than naive `Add` and `Minus`, etc.

Any guidance to solve the problem is appreciated. Below is my code. I post it here only to show how messy the code is. Don't try to compile it, as it is full of type errors.

```
executeString' :: String -> String -> Maybe String
executeString' []     _     = Just ""
executeString' ","    _     = Nothing
-- executeString' source input = Just $ map chr $ elems $ consume 

length' ::String ->  Int 
length' source = right - left 
    where step (l, r) '>' = (l,   r+1)
          step (l, r) '<' = (l+1, r)
          (left, right) = foldl' step (0, 0) source

-- decrement the data pointer 
neverMinus :: Int -> Int 
neverMinus n = if n == 0 then 255 else n - 1 

-- increment the data pointer 
alwaysPlus :: Int -> Int 
alwaysPlus n = if n == 255 then 0 else n + 1 

consume :: String -> String -> (Array Int Int, Array Int Char) 
consume source input = runSTArray $ do 
       pointer <- newArray (0, arrlength') 0  
       forM_ source $ \t -> do 
           pointed <- readArray pointer point 
           elem <- readArray pointer pointed
           isWrong <- readArray pointer error 
           status' <- readArray pointer status 
           when (1 == isWrong) $ return 0 
           when (doJump status') $ return 0
           case t of 
               '>' -> writeArray pointer point (pointed + 1) 
               '<' -> writeArray pointer point (pointed - 1) 
               '+' -> writeArray pointer pointed (alwaysPlus elem) 
               '-' -> writeArray pointer pointed (neverMinus elem) 
               ',' -> do  index <- readArray pointer inputIndex 
                          writeArray pointer pointed (ord $
                                head . drop index input)
                          writeArray pointer inputIndex (index+1)
                          1 
               '[' -> writeArray pointer status jump 
               ']' -> writeArray pointer status execute 
       return pointer
    where arrlength'  = length'' + 4 
          length'' = length' source 
          strlength' = 1 +  foldl' (\count s -> case s of 
                                                 '.' -> count + 1) 0 source 
          point      = length'' + 1
          inputIndex = length'' + 2
          status     = length'' + 3 -- should the program execute current instruction or jump
          error      = length'' + 4 -- if there is program error during execution

-- Program status 
jump    = 1
execute = 0

doJump :: Int -> Bool
doJump jump    = True
duJump execute = False
```

Comment: [Here's some inspiration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/128833/charmander-brainfuck-interpreter-in-haskell).

Comment: Brainfuck is less complex than the typical arithmetic parser. It's equivalent to having a single operator and parentheses. Here's a parser that fits in this comment: `import Text.Parsec; import Text.Parsec.Char; data BF = Op Char | Loop [BF] deriving Show; main = let list =   many cmd; cmd = Op <$> oneOf "<>+-.," <|> loop; loop = char '[' *> (Loop <$> list) <* char ']' in putStrLn .   show $ runParser list () "" "[->+<]"`

Comment: Those two comments are worth their ---weight--- character count in gold, but I'm still voting to close this as *Unclear what you're asking*.

Answer (score 1):

Some tips to write brainfuck interpreter in a language like haskell.

*Initially, I was thinking about writing the program using Array. Immediately after I started to implement the interpreter, I realized how inefficient the interpreter would be because there are many changes to the array. Then I switched to use STArray. But aside from holding an array of data pointers, I also need a mutable reference for the output String, which is impossible in STArray. So I was totally stunned.*

Study about [List Zippers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipper_(data_structure)). It's a data structure which can be defined -> [Left of the pivot element] {Pivot element} [Right of the pivot element] which in code looks like.

```
`data Tape a = Tape [a] a [a]`
```

with that you can easily define `>`, `<`, `+`, `-` etc on this datatype.

*Writing a monadic parser might be a good idea, I thought then. But it turns out I don't know what kind of expressions I should use to model the problem. I only read a few papers on monadic parsing style and that's all. Brainfuck is much more complicated than naive Add and Minus, etc.*

That is not true, Brainfuck is rather less complex than a typical arithmetic parser. as pointed out in one of the comments. i.e something like the following should get you on the right track.

`` stripComments = filter (`elem` "+-<>[],.") ``

```

```
token :: Parser Token
token = const TRight <$> char '>'
  <|> const TLeft  <$> char '<'
  <|> const TInc   <$> char '+'
  <|> const TDec   <$> char '-'
  <|> const TPrint <$> char ','
  <|> const TRead  <$> char '.'
  <|> const TLoopS <$> char '['
  <|> const TLoopE <$> char ']'
```

```

Lastly you will need an evaluation strategy, I would use something like the following for that.
`eval :: String -> Tape Token -> Tape Int -> String`
where 1st argument is the input to the program, `Tape Token` would be the parsed program, `Tape Int` would be the manipulated values on the tape on which you will apply the values and the last argument would be the output.

I believe this should help you get on the right track.

I once did write something similar https://gist.github.com/sherubthakur/16a784e61efbe54d885ad60c6e18f254.